# what is the difference from implementing the js class naming in the react-native like this

Tags: react-native

from some tutorials I see a difference in implementing this native js react class,
I want to know, is there a difference in terms of functions related to the differences in this implementation ??

first like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

}
```

and the second like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {

}

export default App;
```

what is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference when it comes to using it. Either one exports this class member as default. I think it comes down to preference and what you perceive to be a cleaner code.

Some might say that class declaration should be just that: declare the class. And then, if you want to use exports, have them at the bottom, especially if you have several classes in one file that you would want to export. This way all the exports are visible in one section of the code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    // ...
}

class Page extends Component {
    // ...
}

class Service extends Component {
    // ...
}

// you have all of your exports together
export App;
export Page;
export Service;
```

To further expand on that, if you use Typescript, the class declaration can take a lot of characters to fit in one line. And thus if you are trying to write clean, "linted" code, you would want to keep the length of your lines at bay. And to avoid unnecessary long line, you would just do that separately, after the code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

interface State {
    // ...
}

interface Props {
    // ...
}

class App extends Component<Props, State> {
    // ...
}

export default App;
```

In the end of the day, it's up to you or your team, and comes down to purely aesthetic/clean code purposes.

Comment: okay thank you. because I'm a beginner at react native. so I'm a little confused about this

Comment: No problem @NurdhiatMalik ! Happy to clarify

Answer (score 1):

There's not really any difference. It just means if you wanted to you can do extra things to the class before exporting it. For example you could add propTypes like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class App extends Component {

}

const appPropTypes = {
  someProp: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

App.propTypes = appPropTypes

export default App;
```

Though with propTypes you can also just add them as `static` properties inside the class itself. Generally I tend to use `export default class...` just to keep it concise, but it's a matter of preference.